# what is the difference between "be into" and "be keen on" and "interested in"

Tags: meaning

I am keen on studying English,
I am interested in studying English.

Can you write with some examples?

Comment: Do you mean 'be keen on' for the second term in the title ?

Answer (score 3):

These three terms are synonymous; they mean the same thing.

'Interested in' is the most formal of the three phrases; "keen on" is slightly less formal; and "be into" is a slang.

For example, you might say to a friend: "I'm into studying English these days," or "I'm into English" (or skateboarding, or stamp-collecting, or World of Warcraft...)

Whereas, speaking to someone more respectfully, perhaps an older relative or a teacher, you might say: "I am keen on my English studies."

On a job application, you would be more likely to say: "I am interested in furthering my English studies."

You would not usually use slang on a job application or other formal setting, so it would not be advisable to use slang such as 'being into (something)' in that context. It is not rude exactly, just a more informal, youthful manner of speaking.

On the other hand, it would not be strange to say 'interested in' or 'keen on' in an informal environment. It may sound a little more stilted, but it is still perfectly acceptable English.

Comment: +1 but I consider "keen on" to be fairly informal, not "slightly less formal".

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in register. "To be into sthg" is informal and familiar. "To be keen on" is also familiar but perhaps a little old-fashioned these days. "To be interested in" is the most neutral.